# How are the cross validation and training processes interlinked here?

Tags: python, training, cross-validation, gradient-boosting-decision-trees

Please consider the code given below.

```
# Define categorical and numerical features
categorical_features = X.select_dtypes(
   include=["object"]
).columns.tolist()
print(categorical_features)

numerical_features = X.select_dtypes(
   include=["float64", "int64"]
).columns.tolist()
print(numerical_features)

# Preprocessor
preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
         ("cat", OneHotEncoder(), categorical_features),
         ("num", StandardScaler(), numerical_features),
     ]
)

# Gradient Boosting classifier pipeline
pipeline = Pipeline(
   [
       ("preprocessor", preprocessor),
       ("classifier", GradientBoostingClassifier(random_state=42)),
   ]
)

# Cross validation and training
cv_scores = cross_val_score(pipeline, X_train, y_train, cv=5)
pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

After identifying the categorical and numerical features,
a preprocessor is defined based on these two. This
is followed by a pipeline comprising
the aforementioned preprocessor and a classifier.
Near the end, we perform cross-validation and training.

Apparently, the results from cross-validation are not being used
in the training process. `cv_scores` is not among the arguments
used by `pipeline.fit`.

Are the cross-validation and the training process interlinked in some manner where results or effects from the former are being passed to the latter?